# Android Prevent access to SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I use a sqlite database in my project. The stored data in it must not be available for the user to edit. As I've read here I saw that if you have root access you can alter sqlite database. The only solution would be to encrypt database content, but this would be time consuming for device. Any solution to prevent access to database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd have to use some computationally cheap encryption for that. Afaik, there's no way to prevent a power user to access the contents of your db.

Or store the sensitive data on some protected remote server, not locally.

Comment: Right now I am using AES Encryption. I'll go with that idea. Thank you very much.